# Visitin' versus visiting

Tags: meaning, word-usage, diction

I often see in the literature characters' sentences with "*in'*" instead of "*ing*".

For example:

> "*I am visitin' my lady*" said the young thug.

I have 3 questions:

- What does that convey?
- Is this associated with lower-class individuals?
- Is it actually pronounced differently? As a non native English speaker, I've been taught that I should not pronounce the "g" in "-ing", so it would seem to me that "*visitin'*" and "*visiting*" are pronounced the same.

Comment: It's called *eye dialect*, and tries to imitate speech-as-spoken using creative orthography (so yes, it's actually pronounced differently). Shortening "ing" to "in'" is very standard in both writing and actual speech. It's not associated with "lower class", but it is more casual. But even the "highest class" English speakers do it. They just do it less in formal speech settings and almost never in writing. I'm college-educated and a working professional and I pronounce it this way. On the other hand, "my lady" is something I wouldn't refer to my wife or girlfriend as.

Comment: I tend to think of it more as a signal to imagine some particular affected pronunciation. I wouldn't expect it to only reflect a shortened *ing*. It might signal the entire sentence should be imagined in dialect. Visitin' might be imagined as viz:din. It's a pain to write or read whole swaths of text in eye dialect.

Answer (score 2):

These are actually pronounced differently. The *-ing* is traditionally pronounced as /-ɪŋ/, while *-in'* indicates pronunciation as /-ɪn/. This is the difference between the words *sing* and *sin*. There is no actual phone /g/ associated with either pronunciation.

In the U.S., the pronunciation *-in'* indeed used to be associated with lower-class accents. I believe more and more people are using this pronunciation, so this may no longer the case. But I don't believe this association exists in the U.K. – I have read that in England, upper-class speakers  have been using the pronunciation *-in'* for many years.

Comment: That's interesting. I looked up how they say "sing" on https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sing. I do hear a "g" sound in the US pronunciation, but it's way more tenuous in the UK pronunciation. Do you agree with the way these are pronounced on this website?

Comment: There's not supposed to be a /g/ sound in *sing*.  I think you might be having trouble distinguishing /n/ from /ŋ/, which may be a function of your native language. Try listening to the difference between *singer* (no /g/ sound) and *finger* (a /g/ sound).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that perhaps it conveys a desire to be accepted as part one's peer group, and not appear aloof and overly correct. For that reason, it may sometimes be regarded as lower class. In England, however, there appears have evolved some social merit, and occasional inverted snobbery, in belonging to the so-called 'lower class'.

The sound of 'visitin' is different from the sound of 'visiting'. The sound of the word 'ring' is the target pronunciation. With no emphasis on the 'g', it should sound like neither 'rin' nor 'ring-a'. Many people, I think especially among the younger generation, omit the 'g' when saying words such as 'visiting'. It's a corruption, just  like 'wanna' (want to), and 'gonna' (going to), but it has become commonplace. The latter two examples are frequently used by TV news readers and interviewers. Since this is how so many people speak, you will see these occurring in novels. They are not correct, but that's the way we actually use - and abuse - language.

Comment: 'Upper-class' speakers used to be represented in fiction as dropping the 'g' in this way. For instance, Lord Peter Wimsey in _Whose Body?_ says 'Didn't know Levy had a charmin' daughter.', but this kind of speech is long obsolete. The questioner doesn't say where the quotation about the young thug comes from, but I assume it's meant to represent uneducated speech.